# React-Redux - rank counter table

Tags: reactjs, counter, react-redux

I am currently working on one of FCC's project, specifically to this one:

https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/build-a-camper-leaderboard

I was able to get it working just fine--I am able to click either recent or all-time scores and it will re-render the page accordingly.

The only thing I am missing is rendering the rank number appropriately. As of now, it is just current stack of number 1.

Here's my current code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { recentData } from '../actions/index'
import { allTimeData } from '../actions/index'

export default class TableBoard extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.recentData() //fetch data most recent top
  }
  renderData(userData){
    const name = userData.username;
    const recent = userData.recent;
    const allTime = userData.alltime;
    let rank = 1;
    return(
      <tr key={name}>
        <td>{rank}</td>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{recent}</td>
        <td>{allTime}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
  getRecentData(){
    console.log('recent data')
    this.props.recentData()
  }
  getAllTimeData(){
    console.log('all-time data')
    this.props.allTimeData();
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Camper Name</th>
            <th
              onClick={this.getRecentData.bind(this)}
              >Points in 30 days
            </th>
            <th
              onClick={this.getAllTimeData.bind(this)}
              >All-time Posts
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.FCCData.map(this.renderData)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    FCCData: state.collectData
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({ recentData, allTimeData }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TableBoard);
```

How can I add extra information into renderData function to display the rank correctly? I am assuming I need to an counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass index into map

```
 renderData(item,index){
    const name = item.username;
    const recent = item.recent;
    const allTime = item.alltime;
    return(
      <tr key={name}>
        <td>{index+1}</td>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{recent}</td>
        <td>{allTime}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
```

Table Body

```
<tbody>
    {this.props.FCCData.map(this.renderData}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Awesome, that did the job. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. More code, more experience. Keep coding, keep solving problems. Good luck.